# Blender UV not correct when used in Unreal Engine

Tags: materials, uv, uv-image-editor

I've been learning a lot about Blender and I was able to make my Golem model with an armature and some animations. At the time of trying to put the model in Unreal Engine, everything goes good but the material.
I unwrapped a procedural material and exported the UV texture afterwards but in the exterior faces of the object, the material is streched while in the interior, it looks perfect.
I was wondering if this is a problem when generating the UV or Unreal Engine.
I'm using Blender 3.6

This is part of the model in Blender
[image]

This is part of the model in Unreal Engine
[image]

This is the inner part of the model in Unreal Engine
[image]

Comment: The UV mapping done in Blender was perfectly done. The material at Unreal Engine was using another UV channel instead the correct one.